# Is it possible to give nested Apex:Repeat in the vf pages? If possible what is the limit?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

Is it possible to give nested Apex:Repeat in the vf pages? If possible what is the limit?

In my requirement i have to show the Parent Record in one Row and respective child's of that parent in the same row as row span. So i move to apex:Repeat.
But for this scenario i have to use nested Apex:Repeat as my knowledge.

Comment: yes you can use nested apex repeat but you need wrapper class for that so that you can have iterative object for child <apex:repeat

Comment: I don't know if there are any limits on the number of nested repeat tags you can have, but there is a collection limit -1000-  per repeat tag..(i believe was mentioned below). As long as you're not hitting the view state limit, you should be good

Answer (score 4):

There is no harm in using nested repeaters in visualforce.

There are lot of applications using the approach

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!value}" var="{!a}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!a}" var="{!b}">
     <!--write your logic here -->
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: @Himanshu Thanks for edit..I was travelling answering from phone.

Comment: Yaah I noticed that with reply ;)

Comment: A part of the question deals with the limit. Is there any documentation on how deep can one go with nested repeats?

Comment: I have not seen any limits around same .Obviously it should be good unless we run into infinity loop or hit view state

Comment: Mo, Himanshu, I added quotes around the tag values.... :)